# Remove Duplicate Data from XML while using redefine in BizTalk

Tags: xml, xsd, biztalk, redefine

I have a schema which is formed by redefining 2 schemas

[image]

Now I have called this schema to another using redefine to add elements to Extn. But the elements from previous schema is repeating with the added element.

[image]

The Elynx Address is the added element. So how to remove the extra data or add element without repeating. The code to redefine used is :

```
xs:redefine schemaLocation="InheritSchema.Redefine">
    <xs:complexType name="commAddress">
      <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
        <xs:extension base="commAddress">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ElynxAddress" type="ElynxAddress" maxOccurs="1"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:redefine>
```

The complex type ElynxAddress is given as :

```
<xs:complexType name="ElynxAddress">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="County" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="Zip" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: This question is not entirely clear - are you trying to do this in a map? are you just trying to design the schema?  What do you actually want removed/de-duplicated?

Comment: I am trying to make another schema so that while mapping I Dont get repeated data. As you can see the Street,State,Zip elemnts are repeating again. I needed to know how to remove that

Comment: Google muenchian grouping biztalk

Comment: What's not clear is whether you are referring to the duplicate definitions in the Schema or you are getting duplicate instances in the map output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping. The particular schema when imported in another schema, does not shows the repeated element. So the issue is solved. :D